# drawing a spirograph: number of lobes and number of 2 pi cycles necessary to complete the figure

Tags: geometry

I am drawing some nice graphics, taking a cue from these wikipedia pages:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(mathematics)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirograph

For the Lissajous and rose curves I understand how to set the parameters and how many "round" the variable angle has to do to complete the figures.

I cannot understand the right parameters for the spirograph.
Sometimes I have to loop *2 pi* many times to close the path.

---

Referring to the equations shown on the wikipedia page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirograph

I am working with cartesian coordinates.

```
x = (1 - k) cos(a) + l k cos(a (1 - k) / k)
y = (1 - k) sin(a) - l k sin(a (1 - k) / k)
```

Questions:

1. Is it possible to predict the outcome of the equation by the parameters *k, l* ?
2. How many times I have to iterate the angle *a* over *2 pi* to have a complete figure?

Examples:

1. not complete
2. too many lobes
3. complete and nice

[image: not complete]
[image: too many lobes]
[image: complete and nice]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please include Mathematica code that you are using to create these figures in the question.

Comment: Hi Domen. Ops... I thought this is the site for general math problems.  I am not using Mathematica and the question is theoretical, not depending on a specific software. If I am off topic, could you please suggest me the correct SO web site?

Comment: Look up  Epitrochoid, Hypotrochoid, Epicycloid, Hypocycloid.

Comment: A general rule of thumb : a wheel with $n$ (resp. $p$)  teeth rolling one on the other is closed when you have completed either $LCM(n,p)/n$ or $LCM(n,p)/p$ "turns" (LCM = Least Common Multiple).

Comment: Hi Jean Marie. On the wikipedia page about Hypotrochoid there is one of the two LCM formulas. Could you please point me to any docs explaining them? Examples: Which to use?  Are they valid also for Epitrochoid?